# A question on generating function

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How to find the generating function of $\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: What is $C$ exactly?

Comment: It's relatively easy if you know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k} = 4^n$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant $C(n,k)$ is $\binom{n}{k}$. Easier to typeset back in the days before computers.

Comment: **Hint:** See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Got it, thanks!

Comment: @user 170039 I tried multiplying both the sides by z^n and summing for all n>=0 and then expanding RHS and then I got lost. Although there are solutions for this problem, however, they all are currently beyond my reasoning as those are employing heavy binomial expansions..

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(z) = \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \binom{2n}{n}z^n$.  Then we can use what Thomas wrote in the comments: \begin{align*}
F(z)^2 = F(z)\cdot F(z) &= \left(  \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \binom{2n}{n}z^n\right) \left( \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \binom{2n}{n}z^n \right)\\
&= \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \left(\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n - 2k}{n - k} \right) z^n \\
&= \sum\limits_{n \geq 0} 4^n z^n \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - 4z}.
\end{align*}

This implies that $F(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4z}}$.